# To save the prediction results as 1 or 0 according to their accuracy and falsehood

Tags: python, machine-learning

I wonder about is there a method or sortcut to assign my prediction result as a number to a matrix? For example my matrix is `result` if model predicts first feature `true` then `result[0]=1` and if it predicts second feature `false` then `result[1]=0` . I use some basic code block to make this matrix for intance multiple loop and pandas functions. But if it is exist, I want two learn the advanced way to do this.Thank you!

Example of my data and `TAU` column is label and other are features:

[image]

This is my code block if model predicts first label as a 0.8 then it become `result=1` and `accuracy=1` or if it predicts wrong for example 0.7 then it become `result=0` and `accuracy=0`,this two matrix same thing.

```
predictions = model.predict_classes(x_test)
pred_np=np.array(predictions,dtype=float).reshape(test_size,1)
y_test_np=np.array(y_test,dtype=float).reshape(test_size,1)
acc=np.all(np.equal(pred_np, y_test_np), axis=1).reshape(test_size,1)
```

For example my code output ( `accuray` column is same `result` matrix)

[image]

By the this way I can get which features that have certain index predicted wrong or true.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your code? It's unclear which library you are using and what is the input/output expected.

Comment: I add some new information about my question , I hope ,I could explain correctly.